# Parse Notifications Come in Twice With Apple Watch

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-watch

I have an Apple Watch app that I used Parse to help build.  When I get a notification from the app, it comes in twice.  I suspect one is delivered to my phone, which the watch shows, and the second actually delivered to the watch. It is quite annoying.  My InterfaceController setup looks like this on the Watch App (watchOS 1):

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [Parse setApplicationId:@"ID"
                  clientKey:@"KEY"];
    NSUserDefaults *testDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.company.appName"];
    NSString *theirUser = [testDefaults objectForKey:@"sessiontoken"];
    NSString *theirPass = [testDefaults objectForKey:@"password"];
    NSLog(@"%@", theirPass);
    if (![testDefaults objectForKey:@"sessiontoken"]) { // No user logged in
        NSLog(@"No");
        self.loginLabel.hidden = NO;
    }

    else {

    [PFUser becomeInBackground:theirUser block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            // The token could not be validated.
        } else {
            // The current user is now set to user.
        }
    }];
    self.loginLabel.hidden = YES;




}
[super awakeWithContext:context];

// Configure interface objects here.
```

}
I have it set up so that when the user logs in on iPhone, it stores a value as key of "sessiontoken" in NSUserDefaults.  If that isn't found on watch, the login label tells them to first login on the iPhone.  Once it detects it, it goes away.  Any suggestions?